# C++ boost thread is missing from your computer

Tags: c++, gcc, boost-thread

I'm having this very strange problem when I try to run my program on code blocks using a g++ compiler. I have installed boost AND used it up until perhaps a week ago, I never had any problems. Today, I returned to a project I was working on and suddenly I get the following error message when I try to run it

> The program can't start because libboost_thread-mgw47-mt-1_53.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Now I've used boost thread before in this program, so I have no idea why I'm getting this. What's also strange is that boost threads work in other projects I have.

How do I go about trying to solve this? Everything seems to be in place, path variables set, compiler, linker options set, etc... Nothing, that I'm awawre of, has been changed since the last time I ran this program successfully. I did update Visual Studio today, but I don't think that should have any effect. I'm not really sure what other information I can give since I have no idea why this is happening. The .dll file does certainly exist, I've tried moving it into the working directory but still get the same error.

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can go about solving this?

Comment: Copy that dll into the program's folder?

Comment: I've tried that as well and that didn't work either.

Comment: @Muckle_ewe What happened when you did that?

Comment: Do you start your app within VS or directly?

Comment: App was run from within code blocks.

Comment: @jozefg I get the exact same error message.  The console window opens then the error message appears in a seperate dialog

Comment: Either you don't have required boost version or something wrong with PATH/IDE settings.

Comment: I'll check out both of those possibilities. What strikes me as strangest is that boost threads do work in other projects, so the problem surely must be some specific project setting. I'll have a play around with the code blocks settings and see if there's something wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler in that project is dynamicly linking the boost thread library,

Probably some misconfigured settings in linker options or your code uses dllimport instead of 'normal' functions which are resolved at compile-time (dllimport resolves functions at runtime - it can't find them in the required library so you get an error).

Your other projects work because they staticly link the boost thread library (provide the corret boost preprocessor definisions for static linking/compiling and include the corresponding cpp/lib files for the thread library) so it's included in the program.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. (note again, I'm using code blocks)

I had everything set up in the global compiler and linker settings (which I thought would enough). I had everything set up in the individual projects compiler settings, but the project that was working also had some extra stuff in the linker settings. So I had everything set, EXCEPT the settings in the Project -> Build Options -> Search Directories -> Linker part, with the project name selected, not debug/release. I added in...
    $(#boost.lib)
    ............\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib
and now it's fine.

Sort of surprised that the global compiler settings doesn't cover the individual project settings, but there you go.

Comment: so... my answer helped or not? Actually this is not an answer and I think you should delete this post and process it in your question under another headline :F